# SQL Server Rollback transaction not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[master_accounting_invoice_change]
(
    @accinvoiceuid uniqueidentifier,
    @invoicenumber nvarchar(50),
    @businessname nvarchar(150),
    @taxid nvarchar(20),
    @total money,
    @subtotal money,
    @taxamount money,
    @discountamount money,
    @invoicedate datetime,
    @createddate datetime,
    @newfolio int OUTPUT
)
AS
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT accinvoiceuid FROM dbo.accounting_invoice WHERE accinvoiceuid = @accinvoiceuid )
        BEGIN

            /* GET NEXT FOLIO FOR INVOICE */
            SELECT @newfolio = ISNULL(MAX(foliocurrent),0) + 1 
            FROM dbo.accounting_sender_folios
            WHERE accsenderuid = @accsenderuid
            AND isactive = 1;

            exec master_accounting_invoice_insert 
            @accinvoiceuid,
            @invoicenumber,
            @businessname,
            @taxid,
            @total,
            @subtotal,
            @taxamount,
            @discountamount,
            @comissionamount,
            @invoicedate,
            @createddate

            /* UPDATE NEXT FOLIO FOR INVOICE */
            UPDATE dbo.accounting_sender_folios
            SET foliocurrent = @newfolio
            WHERE accsenderuid = @accsenderuid
            AND isactive = 1;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @newfolio = @folio;

            exec master_accounting_invoice_update 
            @accinvoiceuid,
            @invoicenumber,
            @businessname,
            @taxid,
            @total,
            @subtotal,
            @taxamount,
            @discountamount,
            @comissionamount,
            @invoicedate,
            @createddate
        END
```

Now, in my C# application I call the stored procedure in order to save changes, but the issue is that the **foliocurrent** is not being rollback when a exception occurs, and then the incremental variable is updated and saved.

Everything is rolled back except the:

```
/* UPDATE NEXT FOLIO FOR INVOICE */
            UPDATE dbo.accounting_sender_folios
            SET foliocurrent = @newfolio
            WHERE accsenderuid = @accsenderuid
            AND isactive = 1;
```

This is the code in the C# application. Is working, the rollback transaction is working but it doesn't rollback the incremental folio.

```
DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection();
conn.Open();
DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

try{
  using (DbCommand cmd1 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("master_accounting_invoice_change"))
  {
    db.AddInParameter(cmd1, "accinvoiceuid", DbType.Guid, dr["accinvoiceuid"]);
    .....
    .....
    .....

    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd1);

    newFolio = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd1, "newfolio"));
  }
}catch(Exception ex){
    // roll back transation
    trans.Rollback();
}
```

Any clue on how to solve this or why is happening?

Appreciate any help in advance.

Alejandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you may have it somewhere in the code, but you need to make sure that you associate the command with the transaction. You also need to make sure that the command is associated to the same connection that the transaction is. I'm not sure what your db.GetStoredProcCommand is doing.

```
db.Connection = conn;
db.Transaction = trans;
```

Comment: I forgot to add the transaction to the db.ExecuteNonQuery. Thanks to remember